# Requiring each cluster to have at least one of each class

Tags: machine-learning, clustering

Is there a name for the clustering problem where each cluster is required to have at least one instance/feature of each class, given that each instance/feature is assigned a class?

If so, pointers to any good papers or other resources about them is also greatly appreciated!

Comment: One object from each class?

Comment: Yup, that is correct.

Comment: But can you tell more about your wishes in the question? How do you see the aim? To help you, here is one proposal starting from which you could say whether and why it doesn't suit. Having k classes, select one point from each class, the k points as much as possible distant to each other. Then simply assign each of the rest n-k points to its closest one among those k.

Comment: The k points do not need to be as distant as possible from each other. My motivating scenario is that I have k different type of public facilities, like hospitals, fire stations, etc. I want to create clusters where each cluster has at least one of each public facility. The clusters are created based on distance (geography), like in K-means clustering. But there is no requirement that instance with class A in cluster 1 is far from instance with class A or B or C in cluster 2.

Answer (score 1):

None of the existing clustering algorithms will solve this for you.

Instead treat this as a generic **optimization problem**. Define a quality function (when is a solution a *good* solution?), and try out different optimization strategies.